# Keras implementation from scratch of word2vec

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, word2vec

I am looking to implement word2vec from scratch in Keras. 
Is there any good, reliable tutorial that explains how to do it?
Or in TensorFlow if there is only in tf and not in keras.

I couldn't find any